# Doctrine не могу сформировать DQL запрос(createQuery не работает)

Tags: symfony3, doctrine2, dql

Приветствую!
Столкнулся с тем, что в Doctrine (Symfony 3) не могу сделать запрос через DQL.
Обыкновенные запросы типа:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
$product = $repository->find($productId);
$product = $repository->findOneByName('Keyboard');
```

отрабатывают.

А вот сделать свой запрос через $query = $em->createQuery не получается

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Cost;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;


       public function showNewAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Cost');
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p
FROM AppBundle:Cost p
WHERE p.price > :price
ORDER BY p.price ASC'
    )->setParameter('price', 19.99);
    $costs = $query->getResult();
    return $this->render('/costs/current.html.twig', [
        'costs' => $costs
    ]);
```

Может не подключаю какие-либо необходимые бандлы?

Comment: Вот в редакторе выглядит так https://yadi.sk/i/JdAHCMIn3TfaaN

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что код должен выглядеть приблезительно следующим образом

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Cost');
 $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');

 $costs = $query->where('p.price > :price')
        ->setParameter('price', 19.99)
        ->orderBy('price', 'ASC')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Дело в том, что не находит сам QueryBuilder вот скрин https://yadi.sk/i/sZl-Hk7h3TgNLK